# How to implement events with ECS?

Tags: c++, architecture, design-patterns, events, entity-component-system

I'm transitioning over to an ECS architecture for a small C++ graphics engine I'm working on and I'm a bit stumped on how to tackle events. One solution I came across was from [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/6dsrzy/ecs_and_event_handling_how_to_handle_events/) basically if I'm understanding it correctly you create an entity whenever an event occurs and then add a component which would be the event type and have data specific to the event.

```cpp
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    if (sdlEvent.type == SDL_KEYDOWN || sdlEvent.type == SDL_KEYUP) {
        Entity keyEventEntity = entityManager.createEntity();
        keyEventEntity.addComponent<KeyEventComponent>(sdlEvent.key.keysym.sym, sdlEvent.type == SDL_KEYDOWN);
    }
}
```

I really like this solution (that's probably the best way to write it though), however, when I inevitably add non ECS systems this probably won't work so would I just create a second more typical event system or would I just use a typical event system to begin with and then perhaps ECS systems could inherit from a event handler interface?

Comment: We have lots of [past Q&A discussing strategies for marrying ECS and events](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=ecs+event) — do any of these cover what you're looking for?